# Ionic cordova livereload on device doesn't work anymore

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, device, livereload

Until today when I lauched

```
    ionic cordova run android -l
```

my app was running in livereload mode on real android device. Suddenly doesn't work anymore. I mean the app runs on device but doesn't listen anymore on file changes, so I cannot see the live changes on device, I must rebuild and rerun the app.

My cli version is 5.4.7.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was updating ionic and cordova frameworks. So I lauched

```
    npm update
    npm update -g ionic
    npm update -g cordova
```

and now the livereload is working as usual.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're connected with the same network, in PC, and in Mobile Device

Comment: My device is connected with a wire to pc

Comment: No it's not working. I think there is a problem with cordova or ionic framework, I'll try to reinstall them